# Is there a very very basic example of simply outputting PHP with a plugin to Twig?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, php

For arguments sake let's say I wanted a plugin that is a basic output:

```
<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
```

So all I am wanting to output is that, and I want that output to be available via twig (ie: {{ helloworld }}

Not passing any information, not doing anything with the craft database, etc. Just very basic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [plugin template variables](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables). You can simply create a method in your plugins variable file that returns anything you want to the template, which would be accessible via `{{ craft.myplugin.customVariable }}`.

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class MypluginVariable
{
    public function customVariable($someProperty = 'defaultValueIfNotDefined')
    {
        return 'Whatever you want!';
    };
}
```